# How do I vote a nomination for a reopen?

Tags: support

I accidently voted my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452313/get-files-recursively-inside-directory-in-ruby) to be reopened.

I don't mind it being marked as a duplicate. However, I do think the question is specifically getting at a shorter solution, while the linked question is asking for any solution at all.

I'd like to add a short answer that there isn't a shorter way to write my solution and then link to the other question for more details.

I know it's bad form to add an answer as an edit to the question but I accidently marked it as a duplicate before I had a chance to add my answer.

So now I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to reopen my question so I can add my short edit as an answer and then close it again as a duplicate?
2. Is it possible to remove my vote to reopen? I'm not sure how.

Comment: Why do you want to remove your vote to reopen if you want to answer the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a solution to the problem then simply *add that to the canonical question* rather than adding it to your question.  There's no reason for you to open a question that you fully recognize is a duplicate just because you want your answer to be on your question.

But anyway, to answer the questions that you asked, no, you cannot unilaterally reopen your question; you need to wait for 4 others (or someone who *does* have the ability to unilaterally reopen the question) to reopen it.

No, you cannot retract your reopen vote, although it will eventually age away if others choose to not reopen it.